# emit socket.io and sailsjs (Twitter API)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I got the twits, I'm printing all of them ok in console, but I would like send the data to the view and I don't know how can I do it using socketio.

any idea?

```
var TwitterController = {

'index': function(req,res) {

var twitter = require('ntwitter');

var twit = new twitter({
  consumer_key: '...',
  consumer_secret: '...',
  access_token_key: '...',
  access_token_secret: '...'
});

twit.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['dublin', 'spain']} , function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.user.screen_name + ': ' + data.text);

    req.socket.emit('tweet', {
                    user: data.user.screen_name,
        text: data.text
    });

  });
});
       res.view();
},
};
module.exports = TwitterController;
```

and in the view I'm trying to print all the twits

```
<ul class="tw"></ul>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');


  jQuery(function($){
    var twList = $('ul.tw');
  });

  socket.on('tweet', function (data) {
    twList.prepend('<li>' + data.user + '</li>');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give Sails v0.9 a try, you'll have an easier time w/ this out of the box since the bundled example handles boilerplate connection logic for you.

The key is, instead of using `res.view()`, serve tweets with `res.json(tweets)`.

In this example, you're using streams, so you can take advantage of `res.pipe(stream)`.

Then you can use sails.io.js on the front-end to send a socket.io request to `/twitter`, and use the results for fun and profit.

> The following front-end code assumes you're using the tiny client-side SDK (sails.io.js) bundled in Sails v0.9.x:

```
socket.get('/twitter', function (tweets) {
  console.log('Got the following tweets from the server :: ', tweets);
}
```

> Keep in mind `socket.get` is just a convenience method on top of `socket.emit` that works with the Sails router out of the box.  You can still do all the custom socket.io things you like if you have pubsub-specific code that you don't want to make accessible via HTTP.
>
> sails.io.js also supports `socket.post`, `socket.put`, and `socket.delete`, with a similar API to the comparable jQuery AJAX methods (e.g. `$.post`)